# Tool or Process to check for AES-NI support on processor?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hardware

[In another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/how-to-choose-a-stream-cipher), Thomas' answer mentioned the AES-NI instruction set, which piqued my curiosity.

Is there a tool or process available out there to check whether the instruction set is available (besides comparing CPU model numbers)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On **Linux** systems, do:

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
```

This will give, for each CPU core, the list of what that core can do. The AES-NI instructions are there when the flag "`aes`" appears in the list of flags. See [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean/43540#43540) for a list of possible flag values.

On **macOS**, do:

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu | grep -i aes
```

If it doesn't find anything, this machine doesn't have AES-NI.

For **Windows**, see this [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/50662/displaying-motherboard-memory-cpu-info).

Comment: THe aes flag only says when you have AES right? Not AES-NI (New instruction set)...

Comment: Wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a low level hardware person any more, but an example from **[this post](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/freebsd-current/2010/5/31/6258262)** regarding a FreeBSD implemention shows you can grab info from Features2:

```
Features2=0x29ee3ff<SSE3,PCLMULQDQ,DTES64,MON,DS_CPL,VMX,SMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,<b17>,DCA,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,POPCNT,AESNI>
```

Comment: You should add how to get this output. e.g. `dmesg | grep Features2` .

Answer (score 4):

On Windows systems, you can use free console tool 
"[Coreinfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx)" from Sysinternals

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [`cpuid`](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html) utility available on a number of OS's (including FreeBSD, Linux, macOS, and NetBSD).

```
cpuid | grep -i aes
  AES instruction                         = true
```

Comment: On macOS, `sysctl -n machdep.cpu | grep -i aes`

Comment: @dchest - that's more of an answer to the original question than a comment about the `cpuid` answer.  But FWIW, it does look like MacPorts has cpuid.

Comment: agreed, added to the accepted reply.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is about the NI (New Instruction) set for AES, NI accelerates the the AES algorithm.

A right answer could be (also according to Intel docs):

`cpuid | grep -i aes | sort | uniq`

If you want to be sure, you can also try the following command:

`sort -u /proc/crypto | grep module`

This really gives the kernel modules that are loaded, which should be `aesni_intel` (together with `aes_x86_64`), to be sure you are using the *full Intel AES-NI* support.